# Under what conditions are such operators well defined?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let H be a hilbert space, and $\phi_k$ a basis, one can define a "diagonal" operator $A$ by $A\phi_k=b_k\phi_k$, Is there a simple condition on the coefficients $b_k$ such that the operator is well defined, i.e $Ax=\sum b_k \langle x,\phi_k\rangle\phi_k$ is well defined for all $x \in H$ ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken,for all square summable sequences $u_n$ we must have $\sum u_n^2b_n^2 \le \infty$ but that's not the "simple" condition I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

The $b_k$s must be bounded.

Clearly this is a *sufficient* condition.

It is also a *necessary* one: if $|b_k|$ is unbounded, then there is a subsequence $b_{k_n}$ such that $|b_{k_n}|>n$, and then we can choose $a_{k_n} = 1/b_{k_n}$ and keep the other $a_i$s zero. Then the $a_{k_n}$ are clearly square summable but $b_{k_n}a_{k_n}=1$ is not.